# How to use loop through a file and delete certain number of rows based upon the first indexed value and then every 100th after?

Tags: python, loops, file

For whatever reason, the modulus part that I included to print every 100th into the file is being skipped... the x[0] != "*" condition works and so does the count = 0 , so I'm not sure what else is going on... any help would be much appreciated!

```
list1 = ['FileA.abc','FileB.abc','FileC.abc']

for lis1 in list1:
    count = 0
    with open(lis1, "r+") as f:
        d = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for i in d:
            x = i.split(",")
            if x[0] != "*":
                f.write(i)
            elif (count = 0) or ((count % 105) = 0):
                f.write(i)
                count = count + 1
            print(count)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: 100th or 105th line?

Answer (score 0):

You're only increasing count when count = 0, so count will be 1.

After that, count does not change and the condition for it to change is when it becomes a multiple of 105 (which will not happen because you didn't change it since the beginning) - you have a semantic deadlock.

You may have to change `count` somewhere outside the `if` block in order to it to make the condition.